# Mirror/"stream" iGPU display over USB-to-HDMI adapter?

Tags: graphics, gpu, intel-graphics, drm, displaylink

Does anyone know any way for to mirror iGPU display over a USB-to-HDMI adapter? For various reasons my laptop can't use the dedicated Nvidia card and all HDMI and USB-C ports are wired to dGPU. iGPU can only access USB 3.0 ports.

I've been using DisplayLink until it became necessary to switch to Hyprland, which after 3 hard days of debugging may lead some to conclusion that it just isn't possible to use DisplayLink on wlroots yet. An alternative one might consider would be mirroring in "some way" the main iGPU display over USB (or network).

It sounds possible - capture the screen - send it over the USB to the display. However, I couldn't find any solution so far. I would greatly appreciate any ideas.

Comment: *iGPU can only access USB 3.0 ports* This is incorrect, no graphics actually access "normal" USB ports. The adapters you mention are DisplayLink or similar technology, it's an additional, external, "graphics". This already existed and worked (poorly) with USB2.0 ports (it still works poorly just to be clear). It has nothing to do with the new USB-C alt mode or Thunderbolt standards.